# Fast way to push_back a vector many times

Tags: c++, vector

I have identified a bottleneck in my c++ code, and my goal is to speed it up.  I am moving items from one vector to another vector if a condition is true.

In python, the pythonic way of doing this would be to use a list comprehension:

```
my_vector = [x for x in data_vector if x > 1]
```

I have hacked a way to do this in C++, and it is working fine.  However, I am calling this millions of times in a while-loop and it is slow.  I do not understand much about memory allocation, but I assume that my problem has to do with allocating memory over-and-over again using `push_back`.  Is there a way to allocate my memory differently to speed up this code?  (I do not know how large `my_vector` should be until the `for`-loop has completed).

```
std::vector<float> data_vector;
// Put a bunch of floats into data_vector
std::vector<float> my_vector;

while (some_condition_is_true) {
    my_vector.clear();
    for (i = 0; i < data_vector.size(); i++) {
        if (data_vector[i] > 1) {
            my_vector.push_back(data_vector[i]);
        }
    }
    // Use my_vector to render graphics on the GPU, but do not change the elements of my_vector 
    // Change the elements of data_vector, but not the size of data_vector
}
```

Comment: When looking for things to help, consulting the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for the container often helps.  It will help you find useful functions like `reserve`.

Comment: btw `push_back` doesn't always allocate memory. `vector` reserves some memory (which you can check by calling `capacity()` method of `vector`), and when the `size` reaches to `capacity`, only then new memory is allocated. But you can always tell `vector` to reserve some memory before doing stuff to it by calling `reserve`

Comment: Do you need `data_vector` after you have copied it to `my_vector`? May be `swap` will suite you?

Comment: @AlexeyGuseynov yes, I need `data_vector` after I have copied it

Comment: Does `data_vector` have a constant size within the `while` loop?

Comment: @ChrisDrew yes, I have amended my comments accordingly

Comment: @flatmouse I have changed the comments to be more clear

Comment: _"I am calling this millions of times in a while-loop"_ Sounds to me like you need to step back and revisit your requirement, as this is a red flag to me.

Comment: One major problem here is " I assume that...". You should determine with certainty that your assumption is correct and that the rendering or the modification of `data_vector` isn't the true bottleneck. (Also, if you're looping over `data_vector` after rendering, you can modify `my_vector` while you're at it.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am writing a program in OpenGL that is only rendering object that are a certain distance away from the camera.  I am able to run my code with 500,000 objects rendering at 60fps.  500,000 objects at 60 fps = millions of times.  data_vector has the locations of the objects, and my_vector has the objects to be rendered after checking their distance.  Distance changes as the scene progresses.  My profiler shows that 22% of my time is spent on the line where I call `push_back`

Comment: You could consider adding items to my_vector when conditions change instead of scanning all objects all the time. Might be faster depending on how many changes you have.

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger: Right, and recreating entire containers of data on every frame refresh in a graphics application sounds ludicrous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know if this still belongs on this page, but do you have a better solution?

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger: Without knowing anything at all about your application and what it does? No...

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger: You want a space partitioning data structure such as a BVH. This will potentially give you exponential speedup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), and reserve `data_vector.size()` for `my_vector` initially (as this is the maximum possible number of elements for which your predicate could evaluate to true):

```
std::vector<int> my_vec;
my_vec.reserve(data_vec.size());
std::copy_if(data_vec.begin(), data_vec.end(), std::back_inserter(my_vec),
    [](const auto& el) { return el > 1; });
```

Note that you could avoid the `reserve` call here if you expect that the number of times that your predicate evaluates to true will be much less than the size of the `data_vector`.

Comment: I like this. If wasted memory is a big issue, you can call `shrink_to_fit()` afterwards (even though an implementation is not required to actually shrink).

Answer (score 2):

Though there are various great solutions posted by others for your query, it seems there is still no much explanation for the memory allocation, which you do not much understand, so I would like to share my knowledge about this topic with you. Hope this helps.

Firstly, in C++, there are several types of memory: `stack`, `heap`, `data segment`.

`Stack` is for local variables. There are some important features associated with it, for example, they will be automatically deallocated, operation on it is very fast, its size is OS-dependent and small such that storing some KB of data in the `stack` may cause an overflow of memory, et cetera.

`Heap`'s memory can be accessed globally. As for its important features, we have, its size can be dynamically extended if needed and its size is larger(much larger than `stack`), operation on it is slower than `stack`, manual deallocation of memory is needed (in nowadays's OS, the memory will be automatically freed in the end of program), et cetera.

`Data segment` is for global and static variables. In fact, this piece of memory can be divided into even smaller parts, e.g. BBS.

In your case, `vector` is used. In fact, the elements of `vector` are stored into its internal dynamic array, that is an internal array with a dynamic array size. In the early C++, a dynamic array can be created on the `stack` memory, however, it is no longer that case. To create a dynamic array, ones have to create it on `heap`. Therefore, the elements of `vector` are stored in an internal dynamic array on `heap`. In fact, to dynamically increase the size of an array, a process namely `memory reallocation` is needed. However, if a `vector` user keeps enlarging his or her `vector`, then the overhead cost of `reallocation` cost will be high. To deal with it, a `vector` would firstly allocate a piece of memory that is larger than the current need, that is allocating memory for potential future use. Therefore, in your code, it is not that case that `memory reallocation` is performed every time `push_back()` is called. However, if the `vector` to be copied is quite large, the memory reserved for future use will be not enough. Then, `memory allocation` will occur. To tackle it, `vector.reserve()` may be used.

I am a newbie. Hopefully, I have not made any mistake in my sharing.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code twice, first time only counting, how many new elements you will need. Then use `reserve` to already allocate all the memory you need.

```
while (some_condition_is_true) {
    my_vector.clear();
    int newLength = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data_vector.size(); i++) {
        if (data_vector[i] > 1) {
            newLength++;
    my_vector.reserve(newLength);

    for (i = 0; i < data_vector.size(); i++) {
        if (data_vector[i] > 1) {
            my_vector.push_back(data_vector[i]);
        }
    }
    // Do stuff with my_vector and change data_vector
}
```

Comment: Note: changed to `reserve`. Originally I had `resize`, which is wrong of course.

Comment: You have a good solution from a high-level perspective, but your implementation could do with some work. It can be _much_ terser and clearer. Look through the other examples to see how to make the standard library work for you, and avoid writing out lots of loops and conditionals by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt allocating `my_vector` is the problem, especially if the `while` loop is executed many times as the capacity of `my_vector` should quickly become sufficient.

But to be sure you can just reserve capacity in `my_vector` corresponding to the size of `data_vector`:

```
my_vector.reserve(data_vector.size());

while (some_condition_is_true) {
    my_vector.clear();
    for (auto value : data_vector) {
      if (value > 1)
          my_vector.push_back(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux you can reserve memory for `my_vector` to prevent `std::vector` reallocations which is bottleneck in your case. Note that reserve will not waste memory due to overcommit, so any rough upper estimate for reserve value will fit your needs. In your case the size of `data_vector` will be enough. This line of code before `while` loop should fix the bottleneck:

```
my_vector.reserve(data_vector.size());
```